# File name with Hebrew and English letters arrangment

Tags: java, string, hebrew

I have a file name: "אפיון הפצת UCM.doc".

When i write the file from right to left it showes: "UCM.doc אפיון הפצת"

Is there is a way to arrange the String so that the file extension will appear at the end of the string.

Instead of "UCM.doc אפיון הפצת",  "doc.UCM אפיון הפצת".

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear how do you create the file name. And how is java related to this? Are you creating the file name in java?

Comment: @AlexR i take the file name as a string, so it can be related as a given string

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are confusing with typing in Eclipse or other Java IDE. If you are on Windows just write the string you want in Notepad and then copy and paste it as is into java IDE. Microsoft supports RTL exactly as you are expecting.